# Deploy to Heroku button doesnt work properly? (since the hack?)

Tags: deployment, heroku

I get an error when i try to setup a server via one click: https://www.heroku.com/deploy/?template=https://github.com/worldpeaceenginelabs/gun

But if I do it manually on the Heroku website, logged-in, via Dashboard, New, New App, and choose Deployment Method = Github, and choose the same repo from my connected Github account, it works out without any error.

I tried it with different repos from different devs, its definitely Heroku and not the configuration of my/our repos.

I cant tell that the Heroku support, since i am a free member. Only paid members can tell Heroku bugs/errors via the support tool (whats kind of stupid)

This is via 1 click link (fails)
[image]

And this is, when i do it manually (works)
[image]
[image]